# How to compare UID and another child key in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to connect the current user id with the same key in Android, but in another child node, I am searching from tow days, but cant find any solution, I can only get uid, but can't get the other id which I want to compare for retrieving data.

Can any one help me how to find the child key which is actually uid in another field? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Can you post an example of your database, a short clip of the JSON you are referring to.

Comment: Why not just use the uid as the key in the users node?

Comment: Rohit bro i am very new, please how to do this,

Comment: rustcode sir i want to just get the Id in Userinfo as string ?? aisa ho sakta haikiya ?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you want to do and also post your code.

Comment: sir simple i want to get this CP9l8L1viLU77KrEOEDj2tNRCYq2 id in UserInfo, and assign to String, how to do this please.... see pic in question..

Comment: I understand that you want to get the uid, but you say you already have it. This is confusing, so could you please let me know why you need to do this?And also post your code.

Comment: sir can you understand hindi ??? :) my english is too weak

Comment: sir wo Key Chahiye mujhay, kis tara get karoon usko,,,, baki mai kr doonga... uid to get kr sakta hoon, userinfo kay ander jo key hai wo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In English:

If your `DatabaseReference` is pointing at the `users` node, then use `getParent()` to go to the root node, then use `getChild(<UID here>)` to get a reference to that node.

Hindi Mein:

agar aapke `DatabaseReference` `users` node par ishaara kar raha hai, toh `getParent ()` ka upayog karein, root node tak jaane ke lie. Phir `getChild("UserInfo").getChild(<UID here>)` us node tak jaane ke lie.

In code:

```java
String uid = "CP9l8L1viLU77KrEOEDj2tNRCYq2"
DatabaseReference mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
DatabaseReference refToYourUserid = mRef.getParent().getChild("UserInfo").getChild(uid);
```