# How to call another table attribute with uid? - firebase flutter

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter, dart

My problem similar to this [How to compare UID and another child key in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42152432/how-to-compare-uid-and-another-child-key-in-firebase)

I'm trying to create a similar code from that thread but it didn't work

This is my firebase https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBpn7.jpg

```
StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseDatabase.instance
            .reference()
            .child("questions")
            .onValue,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Event> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            Map<dynamic, dynamic> map = snapshot.data.snapshot.value;
            return GridView.builder(
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 1,
                childAspectRatio: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4),
                mainAxisSpacing: 16.0,
              ),
              itemCount: map.values.toList().length,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, top: 16),
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Container(
                  color: bgSecondaryColor,
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Flexible(
                          child: Text(
                            parse(parse(map.values.toList()[index]["question"]).body.text).documentElement.text,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              CircleAvatar(
                                backgroundImage: NetworkImage('https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/7693/catfront.png'),
                                backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreen,
                                radius: 24.0,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                //I want to call the "name" attribute in users here,
                              ),

                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),

                  ],
                ),
                );
              },
```

Sorry im a total newbie in both flutter and firebase. Kind regards from me. Thank you